# Importing project app module issue

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I import project in android studio I get a very bad structure. It goes like this.

[image]

What I want it to be like

[image]

I am trying this for hours but can't import it properly. I tried it importing it as android studio, gradle project. I also tried importing app module and even tried creating app module separately but did not come up with a solution. The original project is here - https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/tree/4.02_start_code_for_lesson_4 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking out the project from github I got could see the same problem;
In `build.gradle` there's a line that needs fixing:

Line 21:
`it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey`

Since there is no variable `MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey` gradle sync will fail and you will get the project view instead of the Android project view.

If you try for example:

```
it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', "\"MY_API_KEY\""
```

To get an open weather api key you can check for more information [here on openweathermap](http://openweathermap.org/appid).

Comment: I tried setting the key, and it is not working still. Did it work for you?

Comment: Did you get a compilation error ? View still invalid? Project view works for me after updating the `buildConfigField`. However I updated my post, you need to wrap the api key like this `"\"MY_API_KEY\""` for it to compile, my bad :)

Comment: Thanks, I did some more changes (sdk version) to get it to work. I did not know gradle errors can make android studio this mad :p